# Direct two web pages to https while maintaining the rest in http

Tags: .htaccess

I am successfully directing my profile page to https while keeping the rest in http. I am having trouble adding another page to be directed to https without causing an infinite loop.

```
The page I am trying to add the list to be directed to https is 
"mywebsite.com.index.php?r=user/login". 

RewriteEngine On
# Go to https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=user/profile$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/index\.php\?r=user/profile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^r=user/profile$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: You have HTTPS set up. Why not use it for everything?

Comment: It is not an option as certain apps can't listen if it is so.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What apps would break by a website using HTTPS?

Comment: shiny server. Do you know how to add the rule? I would appreciate your help.